# Angular/UI Router can't scroll when list is populated

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've got a list of items which I load from an API, so when my page loads I send an AJAX request, update my scope with the data and my list HTML list is populated.

Now, there is no issue when I load the page directly, but when using UI router the following happens:

- Navigating to page directly (reloading the browser) - everything works fine, the list is populated and I can scroll.
- Navigate to the page via another state (using `ui-sref`), the list loads via AJAX, the HTML is updated. However I'm unable to scroll if the list breaks the window height.

I've currently got `html, body { height: 100%; }`, but changing any of these has no effect. Do I need to re-calutate the window height? Why would this only happen when I navigate to the page/state from another?

Can I force UI Router to re-calculate window height on each state load or similar?

Comment: Are you using some front-end framework like bootstrap or semantic?

Comment: It's a theme, which is Bootstrap based yeah.

Comment: Then you'll likely need to re-initialize whatever tab/modal/etc that the content is on.